# Conda update all wants to remove all packages

Tags: python, anaconda

I've downloaded latest anaconda and when I want to update all, it wants to remove all packages. Any idea about what is going on?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda update --all
    Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
    Solving environment: done

    ## Package Plan ##

      environment location: C:\Users\marek\Anaconda3


    The following packages will be REMOVED:

      _anaconda_depends-2019.03-py37_0
      alabaster-0.7.12-py37_0
      anaconda-custom-py37_1
      anaconda-project-0.8.3-py_0
      astroid-2.2.5-py37_0
      astropy-3.2.1-py37he774522_0
      atomicwrites-1.3.0-py37_1
      babel-2.7.0-py_0
      backports.os-0.1.1-py37_0
      backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0-py37_2
      bitarray-0.9.3-py37he774522_0
      bkcharts-0.2-py37_0
      blas-1.0-mkl
      blosc-1.16.3-h7bd577a_0
      bokeh-1.2.0-py37_0
      boto-2.49.0-py37_0
      bottleneck-1.2.1-py37h452e1ab_1
      cloudpickle-1.2.1-py_0
      comtypes-1.1.7-py37_0
      console_shortcut-0.1.1-3
      contextlib2-0.5.5-py37_0
      curl-7.64.1-h2a8f88b_0
      cycler-0.10.0-py37_0
      cython-0.29.11-py37ha925a31_0
      cytoolz-0.9.0.1-py37hfa6e2cd_1
      dask-2.0.0-py_0
      dask-core-2.0.0-py_0
      distributed-2.0.1-py_0
      docutils-0.14-py37_0
      et_xmlfile-1.0.1-py37_0
      fastcache-1.1.0-py37he774522_0
      flask-1.0.3-py37_0
      get_terminal_size-1.0.0-h38e98db_0
      gevent-1.4.0-py37he774522_0
      greenlet-0.4.15-py37hfa6e2cd_0
      h5py-2.9.0-py37h5e291fa_0
      hdf5-1.10.4-h7ebc959_0
      heapdict-1.0.0-py37_2
      html5lib-1.0.1-py37_0
      icc_rt-2019.0.0-h0cc432a_1
      imageio-2.5.0-py37_0
      imagesize-1.1.0-py37_0
      importlib_metadata-0.17-py37_1
      intel-openmp-2019.4-245
      isort-4.3.21-py37_0
      itsdangerous-1.1.0-py37_0
      jdcal-1.4.1-py_0
      joblib-0.13.2-py37_0
      jupyter-1.0.0-py37_7
      jupyter_console-6.0.0-py37_0
      keyring-18.0.0-py37_0
      kiwisolver-1.1.0-py37ha925a31_0
      krb5-1.16.1-hc04afaa_7
      lazy-object-proxy-1.4.1-py37he774522_0
      libcurl-7.64.1-h2a8f88b_0
      libssh2-1.8.2-h7a1dbc1_0
      libxslt-1.1.33-h579f668_0
      llvmlite-0.29.0-py37ha925a31_0
      locket-0.2.0-py37_1
      lxml-4.3.4-py37h1350720_0
      matplotlib-3.1.0-py37hc8f65d3_0
      mccabe-0.6.1-py37_1
      mkl-2019.4-245
      mkl-service-2.0.2-py37he774522_0
      mkl_fft-1.0.12-py37h14836fe_0
      mkl_random-1.0.2-py37h343c172_0
      mock-3.0.5-py37_0
      more-itertools-7.0.0-py37_0
      mpmath-1.1.0-py37_0
      msgpack-python-0.6.1-py37h74a9793_1
      multipledispatch-0.6.0-py37_0
      networkx-2.3-py_0
      nltk-3.4.3-py37_0
      nose-1.3.7-py37_2
      numba-0.44.1-py37hf9181ef_0
      numexpr-2.6.9-py37hdce8814_0
      numpy-1.16.4-py37h19fb1c0_0
      numpy-base-1.16.4-py37hc3f5095_0
      numpydoc-0.9.1-py_0
      openpyxl-2.6.2-py_0
      packaging-19.0-py37_0
      pandas-0.24.2-py37ha925a31_0
      partd-1.0.0-py_0
      path.py-12.0.1-py_0
      pathlib2-2.3.4-py37_0
      patsy-0.5.1-py37_0
      pep8-1.7.1-py37_0
      pluggy-0.12.0-py_0
      ply-3.11-py37_0
      powershell_shortcut-0.0.1-2
      py-1.8.0-py37_0
      pycodestyle-2.5.0-py37_0
      pycrypto-2.6.1-py37hfa6e2cd_9
      pycurl-7.43.0.3-py37h7a1dbc1_0
      pyflakes-2.1.1-py37_0
      pylint-2.3.1-py37_0
      pyodbc-4.0.26-py37ha925a31_0
      pyparsing-2.4.0-py_0
      pyreadline-2.1-py37_1
      pytables-3.5.2-py37h1da0976_1
      pytest-5.0.0-py37_0
      pytest-arraydiff-0.3-py37h39e3cac_0
      pytest-astropy-0.5.0-py37_0
      pytest-doctestplus-0.3.0-py37_0
      pytest-openfiles-0.3.2-py37_0
      pytest-remotedata-0.3.1-py37_0
      pywavelets-1.0.3-py37h8c2d366_1
      qtawesome-0.5.7-py37_1
      qtconsole-4.5.1-py_0
      rope-0.14.0-py_0
      scikit-image-0.15.0-py37ha925a31_0
      scikit-learn-0.21.2-py37h6288b17_0
      scipy-1.2.1-py37h29ff71c_0
      seaborn-0.9.0-py37_0
      simplegeneric-0.8.1-py37_2
      singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py37_0
      snappy-1.1.7-h777316e_3
      snowballstemmer-1.9.0-py_0
      sortedcollections-1.1.2-py37_0
      sortedcontainers-2.1.0-py37_0
      sphinx-2.1.2-py_0
      sphinxcontrib-1.0-py37_1
      sphinxcontrib-applehelp-1.0.1-py_0
      sphinxcontrib-devhelp-1.0.1-py_0
      sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp-1.0.2-py_0
      sphinxcontrib-jsmath-1.0.1-py_0
      sphinxcontrib-qthelp-1.0.2-py_0
      sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml-1.1.3-py_0
      sphinxcontrib-websupport-1.1.2-py_0
      spyder-3.3.5-py37_0
      spyder-kernels-0.5.0-py37_0
      sqlalchemy-1.3.5-py37he774522_0
      statsmodels-0.10.0-py37h8c2d366_0
      sympy-1.4-py37_0
      tblib-1.4.0-py_0
      toolz-0.9.0-py37_0
      unicodecsv-0.14.1-py37_0
      werkzeug-0.15.4-py_0
      win_unicode_console-0.5-py37_0
      wrapt-1.11.2-py37he774522_0
      xlrd-1.2.0-py37_0
      xlsxwriter-1.1.8-py_0
      xlwings-0.15.8-py37_0
      xlwt-1.3.0-py37_0
      zict-1.0.0-py_0
      zipp-0.5.1-py_0
```

Comment: [Report](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/new) the issue to the Anaconda team and don't forget to include all the required information. I'm tempted to say that your problem might be caused by the new conda 4.7.5. I sure had [problems](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11057) with it. Anyway, I suggest trying the new Anaconda 2019.07 which has just been released. Take note that there's an [issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4771) with jupyter notebook.

Comment: Today (2023-04-30) with Ancaonda 23.3.1 in Windows 11 the problem still exists.

After running "conda update -n base conda" the environment is destroyed. Most of the core packages were removed.