# Conda update conda does extra stuff and destroy my anaconda install

Tags: anaconda

I'm on Windows, download a new version of anaconda (64bit) and installed. When I do a "conda update conda", I'm getting a weird extra line:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTVVp.png)
Note the 
"(base) C:\Users\marcelha>ET _sysp=%~dpA"
I didn't type that (obviously), but conda did.

When I do "conda update --all" I experience the same as [Conda update all wants to remove all packages](https://superuser.com/questions/1456970/conda-update-all-wants-to-remove-all-packages)

When I do so tha Anaconda Prompt is even gone from my computer and the terminal inside Jupyter Lab does not ahve an input line anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anaconda has a few problems with updates at the moment. The disappearing Anaconda prompt is discussed here: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/8794. A solution from that page that worked for me was to open Anaconda Navigator and install console_shortcut to the base(root) environment.

The problem of conda update removing all packages is discussed here: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8842. There doesn't appear to be a single solution at the moment although some possible workarounds. I haven't tried any yet for fear of messing up Anaconda on my machine so can't say how successful they are.

Comment: Update 2023-04-30.  The problem still exists.


After running "conda update -n base conda" the environment is destroyed. Most of the core packages are removed.